# HTML Modal won't open

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-modal

I wrote a HTML code like this:

`index.cshtml`:

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/MainLayout.cshtml";
}

<h1>Satışlar Sayfası</h1>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" itemid="openModalButton">
    Satış Yap
</button>
<div class="modal" itemid="Modal1">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h2 class="modal-title">Satış Yapma Ekranı</h2>
            </div>
            <form>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <label>Ürün Adı</label>
                    <input type="text" name="Urun" class="form-control" />
                    <br />
                    <label>Ürün Markası</label>
                    <input type="text" name="marka" class="form-control" />
                    <br />
                    <label>Müşteri Adı Soyadı</label>
                    <input type="text" name="musteri" class="form-control" />
                    <br />
                    <label>Müşteri Telefonu</label>
                    <input type="text" name="telefon" class="form-control" />
                    <br />
                    <button class="btn btn-info">Verileri Kaydet</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#openModalButton").click(function(){
    $("#Modal1").modal();
  });
});
</script>
```

When I click the `openModalButton` button with an id, I want the modal named `Modal1` to open, but it does not open. While it works in the training [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VEwB3P-Dr-E&list=PLKnjBHu2xXNNRPqfdZC6hNmJKOqIIpqNj&index=46) I watched, it does not work for me.

How can I solve this problem? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Did you include the bootstrap js file in the index.html file?

Comment: what version of bootstrap are you using? they changed the expected data tag names in a recent version

Comment: @Sander-Verk No. Because it does not add it to the `index.html` file in the training video I watched.

Comment: @TZHX It is using version v5.1.0.

Comment: then yes, you'll need to adjust your markup -- refer to the [relevant documentation for more information](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/modal/)

Comment: @EmirBolat you should add a reference to the JS files of bootstrap. You can see some CDN examples in the post of Zain Ejaz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `itemid` instead of `id`

Please replace `itemid` with `id` in modal like this

`<div class="modal" id="Modall">`

and one more important thing use `data-href="#Modall"` attribute in button, and remove `itemid` attribute.

You have no need to do a custom javascript. just simply add these CDNs

JQuery
`<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.6.0/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>`

Popper JS
`<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>`

Latest compiled JavaScript
`<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>`